Controller integration test with Mockwebserver
I am trying to create a integration test for a simple controller that implements a Service class that sends a get request to a thrid party and returns a response. I want to implement a test using the MockWebserver and to cover the service class and controller and the test is as follows
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["spring.profiles.active=dev"])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class EndpointTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = JacksonMapperUtil.defaultRequestObjectMapper()
fun `testFunction `() {
        val mockedResponse = MockResponse()
        mockedResponse.setResponseCode(200)
        mockedResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
        mockedResponse.setBody(
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
                PolicyListResponseMessage(),
            ),
        )
        mockWebServer.enqueue(mockedResponse)

        val mvcResult =
            mockMvc
                .perform(
                    get("$BASE_PATH/test") // Base url is configured in the properties and correct url is called
                    .header("x-session-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .header("x-request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString()),
                )
        val request: RecordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest()
        assertEquals("/api-url-two", request.path)
    }

This test does not run beyond the takeRequest()
This is my webclient
 suspend fun getList(mandate: String): ListResponseMessage =

        try {
                webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri {
                        it
                            .path(URL)
                            .build()
                    }.httpRequest {
                        it
                            .getNativeRequest<HttpClientRequest>()
                            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(cardsProperties.timeout))
                    }.retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(ResponseMessage::class.java)
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                    .onErrorResume { err-> err.printStackTrace(); Mono.empty() }
                    .blockOptional().orElseThrow { Exception("Let this run") }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            throw TechnicalException("Web client exception")
        }
}

This is my reference.

Is it possible to achieve my goal at all. I can make the test wokring only for the service class.
If not if there is a way to write a test without mocking the web client.

